# Sonar qube issue in using aes-256-cbc algoritm, stating Make sure that encrypting data is safe here

Tags: node.js, encryption, sonarqube, static-analysis

I am using sonarqube to code quality of my nodejs app.
I am using npm crypto package to encrypt and decrypt.

Sonar qube thrown issue

> Make sure that encrypting data is safe here.

Issue mentioned at my code sinppet is below,

```
let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', Buffer.from(secret_obj.key), crypto.randomBytes(16));
```

I see this

> The Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) encryption algorithm can be used with various modes. Galois/Counter Mode (GCM) with no padding should be preferred to the following combinations which are not secured:
> Electronic Codebook (ECB) mode: Under a given key, any given plaintext block always gets encrypted to the same ciphertext block. Thus, it does not hide data patterns well. In some senses, it doesn’t provide serious message confidentiality, and it is not recommended for use in cryptographic protocols at all.
> Cipher Block Chaining (CBC) with PKCS#5 padding (or PKCS#7) is susceptible to padding oracle attacks

But it is not clear to me,so what is the way to clear this issue from a nodejs app.

Comment: Do you also see the last sentence in the quoted text? `aes-256-cbc` includes CBC. I'd assume it expects you to check if you really need that particular flavour, and then either change it or mark as false positive.

Comment: CBC can be secure for storage or if used together with HMAC in encrypt-then-mac. You say "thrown issue" but I presume it is a warning. I'm not entirely sure how the IV is stored in this case by the way, it's a bit weird that a random value is generated but seemingly never stored. TBH, there should be a warning to use this library wholesale, but that doesn't leave much.